# Cannot get nextcloud listening on port 82

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, nextcloud

I've installed nextcloud with snap and configured it to listen to port 82 with `sudo snap set nextcloud ports.http=82`, firewal is opened on that port as well but it doesn't respond.

investigating, it seems that it's listening to port 82 but on ipv6 only (pid 5231):

```
ubuntuadmin@ubuntu-1804-srv:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
[sudo] password for ubuntuadmin:
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9236          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2476/gitaly
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      844/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1275/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2464/grafana-server
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1711/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5050            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2351/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2351/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8060            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2351/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9121          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2400/redis_exporter
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9090          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2412/prometheus
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9187          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2438/postgres_expor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9093          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2420/alertmanager
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2488/registry
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1512/mysqld
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9100          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2419/node_exporter
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9229          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2239/gitlab-workhor
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3156/unicorn master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9168          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2418/puma 4.3.1.git
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2351/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8082          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2368/sidekiq 5.2.7
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1275/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1711/master
tcp6       0      0 :::9094                 :::*                    LISTEN      2420/alertmanager
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9168                :::*                    LISTEN      2418/puma 4.3.1.git
tcp6       0      0 :::82                   :::*                    LISTEN      5231/httpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           844/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           4558/mdns-publisher
udp6       0      0 :::9094                 :::*                                2420/alertmanager
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                4558/mdns-publisher
```

(nginx is for Gitlab)

Why ??
What do I have to change or add to tell him to listen on `tcp:`?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

From the [snap source](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/blob/28a96001c0707a3c4b505deb0934eb74a2b3718a/src/apache/conf/httpd.conf#L21), it seems apache is set up to listen on [IPv4-mapped IPv6](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html#ipv6) socket:

> If you want Apache to handle IPv4 and IPv6 connections with a minimum of sockets, which requires using IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses, specify the --enable-v4-mapped configure option and use generic Listen directives like the following:
>
> > Listen 80
>
> With --enable-v4-mapped, the Listen directives in the default configuration file created by Apache will use this form. --enable-v4-mapped is the default on all platforms but FreeBSD, NetBSD, and OpenBSD, so this is probably how your Apache was built.
>
> If you want Apache to handle IPv4 connections only, regardless of what your platform and APR will support, specify an IPv4 address on all Listen directives, as in the following examples:
>
> > Listen 0.0.0.0:80
> >     Listen 192.170.2.1:80

[This Github](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/331) issue seems to also support my theory.

Until that gets fixed I see a couple of options to work around:

1. use `socat` to set up forwarding from ipv4 to ipv6 (see [this SE answer](https://superuser.com/questions/722322/how-to-transparently-tunnel-a-port-from-ipv4-to-a-remote-ipv6-device))
2. use workaround [provided on github](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/134#issuecomment-575904440) (which basically involves setting up nginx and reverse-proxying the apache)
3. tweak the file and rebuild the snap from source?

Comment: Maybe it's the solution to my problem but as I'm really not expert in web server configuration, I don't really see how to adapt it in that case. As I said, I already have a nginx server running Gitlab on port 80.

Comment: What about `socat` then? Seems pretty easy and should do the job.

Comment: `socat TCP4-LISTEN:82,fork,su=nobody TCP6:[::1]:82` should probably do the trick in your case. Just make sure to run this as root because 82 is a privileged port

Comment: In fact after 2 weeks I tried to access just now to nextcloud through the defined port 82 and it works. I didn't do anything, nextcloud is always listening on ipv6 but I supposed that a leprechaun came on my server and fixed the problem... Sorry, I really cannot explain what happened.